# Python thread debugging

Tags: python, multithreading, debugging, pdb

I am debugging a python program with pdb. The program will start a new thread.

```
newThread = Thread(group = None,target = dosomething,name = "thename",
                               args = (),kwargs = {})

def dosomething():
    balaba
```

Use the normal pdb command e.g. -b to set break point in the line of the new thread(e.g. line of balaba), seems will not trigger the breakpoint.

The question I want to ask is: is there a way I can break into the new thread target function to look into the behavor the new thread?

Comment: This code doesn't run. Could you past your real code?

Answer (score 1):

One problem to begin with, you have to explicitly start the thread by using `.start()` - they do not start automatically when you create your `Thread` object (assuming you are using Python's built in threading library?).

```
newThread.start()
```

then see if your line of code is triggered using your debug method.